# Put all values of dict in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, key-value, concatenation

I'm looking to extract dict values by key, and I've attempted to add those values to an empty array using the concat() function, however it's printing the values but within their own arrays (atleast it appears that way since each value is surrounded by unique sets of brackets).

```
var dict = {Name: 'Chris', Height: 150, Location: 'New York'};
var dictVal = new Array(); 

for (var key in dict) {
  var val = dict[key];
  console.log(dictVal.concat(val));
}
```

How do I merge the values so they live within their own single set of brackets to denote the list of values within `dictVal`?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers. You can even go back through your history https://stackoverflow.com/users/6860252/mr-jibz?tab=questions and accept answers retroactively as you have mostly unaccepted answers on most of your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake that you're making is that [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a new array meaning

```
dictVal = dictVal.concat(val);
```

is what you want in order to get the result that you want. Alternatively you can also do

```
for (var key in dict) {
  var val = dict[key];
  dictVal.push(val);
  console.log(dictVal);
}
```

if you don't want to generate new arrays.

---

Moreover, there are better ways to do what you want for example mapping the keys of the object to the values:

```
var dict = {Name: 'Chris', Height: 150, Location: 'New York'};
var dictVal = Object.keys(dict).map(key => dict[key]);
```

Iterating through [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is usually preferable to a `for...in` because

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop **(the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well)**.

and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) just saves you several lines of code.

---

Also as a side note using `new Array()` is generally not common. You'd want to do

```
var dictVal = []
```

just to be in better accordance with common JS conventions.

Comment: when I try using `Array.concat` the way you've shown, it prints a growing list of values in three lines, i.e. `[ 'Chris' ]` then `[ 'Chris', 150 ]` then `[ 'Chris', 150, 'New York' ]`....why?

Comment: @Mr.Jibz well that's exactly what's happening isn't it? You're adding a new value on each iteration of the for loop. If you just want to print the final result move the `console.log` outside of the for loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: you're absolutely right, newbie question, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: the goat of stack answers

Answer (score 4):

You may do as follows in modern browsers;

```js
var dict       = {Name: 'Chris', Height: 150, Location: 'New York'},
    dictValues = Object.values(dict);
console.log(dictValues);
```

Comment: Here's the documentation for Object.values():  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values